# Why can't I change the size of my profile picture in my Sign In and Sign Up code?

Tags: html, css

So I have been coding for a Sign In/ Sign Up form. I have no clue as to why the profile-img is not changing its height or width!

Here is my CSS:

```
.form-signin
{
max-width: 330px;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox
{
font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control
{
position: relative;
font-size: 16px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus
{
z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"]
{
margin-bottom: -1px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"]
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.account-wall
{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.login-title
{
color: #555;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
display: block;
}
.profile-img
{
width: 96px;
height: 96px;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
display: block;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.need-help
{
margin-top: 10px;
}
.new-account
{
display: block;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <font face="Arial Narrow"><h1 class="text-center login-title">Hello</h1>
        <div class="account-wall">
            <img class="profile-img" src="butterfly.jpg"
                alt="">
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="">
            <div class="about"><font face="Arial Narrow"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus></div></font>
            <div class="about"><font face="Arial Narrow"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></div></font>
            <div class="about"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                <font face="Arial Narrow">Sign in</button></div></font>
                <br>
                <div class="about">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                <font face="Arial Narrow">Remember me</font>
            </label>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="MokhaSIGNUP.php" class="text-center new-account about">    <font color="black">Become a member! Click here!</font> </a></font>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
```

I have no idea as to what I am doing wrong. When I do add a height and width, and change the numbers, it stays the same.

What should I do? No matter how many times I change the height and width it won't change. Even if I remove the picture, the result is the same. Same size with an error saying no image available. What am I missing? I would display an image as to how it looks, but I don't have enough good reputation.

Comment: you are using deprecated tags such as `center` and `font`, just fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working for me, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/049Lj4LL/8/

I changed the size from 96x96 to 200x200

```
.profile-img
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
display: block;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```